# Minimal APT Update

Tags: apt, package-management, chroot

Is there a way to only update the package lists without running all those scripts afterwards? Maybe even "by hand"?

**My use case:**

- I am trying to install a package via `apt` and `chroot`.
- Unfortunately the package version seems to be outdated in my package list, I get an `404`.
- Therefore I would like to run `apt update` beforehand.
- Unfortunately `apt update` takes forever in `chroot` - at least in my configuration. It gets stuck at running some scripts afterwards, like updating the MOTD.

Comment: Can you specify more in detail what you mean by "all those scripts afterwards"? On my systems, `apt update` refreshes the package lists, builds the dep tree and thats it.

Comment: sure, try running the update with the flag `-oDebug::RunScripts=1` and you will see what I mean. At my case it gets stuck e.g. at `Running external script: 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'`

Comment: This creates no change for me, I guess there is some different configuration involved, though I'm not aware where that would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the offending scripts using

```
apt-config dump|grep Update::Post-Invoke
```

These are all defined in files under `/etc/apt`; rename the files you want to disable with any extension other than `.conf` and they won’t be taken into account.

There’s no `apt` option to disable running all such scripts entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! A combination lead to a working solution

First, find the post-update scripts via

```
grep -ri 'Update::' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

then, rename the resulting scripts like this

```
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier{,.disabled}
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{,.disabled}
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp{,.disabled}
```

run the update and rename them again

```
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier{.disabled,}
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found{.disabled,}
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp{.disabled,}
```